# Map over a function with two arguments in which one argument is a dataframe in R

Tags: r, function, purrr

I have written a function in which to turn rows of a data frame into character vectors.

```
concatenateRow <- function(data, rownum){
 as.character(data[rownum,])
}
```

I want to map `rownum` to `concatenateRow` with the following data:

```
data <- structure(list(A = c("0", "0", "8", "0", "0", "0", "0.0", "0.0", 
"0", "0", "0"), B = c("45", "17", "39", "36", "29", "15", "38", 
"49", "40", "39", "44"), C = c("32", "28", "25", "50", "35", 
"27", "45", "60", "50", "52", "54"), D = c("28", "28", "44", 
"44", "41", "28", "60", "44", "45", "61", "45"), E = c("15", 
"9", "0", "30", "0", "21", "0", "0.0", "15", "10", "0")), row.names = c(NA, 
-11L), class = "data.frame")
```

Like this:

```
rownum <- (1:11)

library(purrr)
new.data <- map(rownum, concatenateRow(data))
```

However, I end up with an empty list of `NULL` with a length of 11. The function works by itself (i.e., `concatenateRow(data, 1)`) but does not work with the `map()` function. Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Thank you so much!

Comment: Use `map(rownum, ~concatenateRow(data, .x))` or `map(rownum, function(x) concatenateRow(data, x))` You need to have a function in the second parameter. Otherwise you are just calling `concatenateRow(data)` once before the iteration.

Comment: `map(rownum, \(x) concatenateRow(data, x))` or `map(rownum, concatenateRow, data = data)`

Comment: @MrFlick that worked beautifully! Thank you very much. Does `~` indicate a function?

Comment: Look at the `.f` argument in `?map`, `~` is the old-style tidyverse shorthand for creating a function using a formula. As you can see, many ways to skin a cat.

Comment: @Axeman thank you very much, I do see that! Am I correct in assuming that when using `~` we refer to the variable to pass through the function as `.x` ?

Comment: From `?map`: _"A formula, e.g. ~ .x + 1. You must use .x to refer to the first argument. "_ So yes, in the one argument case (like `map`), you have to use `.x` (or `.` I think?). For the two argument case (like `map2`), it's `.x` and `.y`. And in the many argument case (like `pmap`), it's `..1`, `..2`, etc.